# TFS: Select only few changsets from merge

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

We have the following branches in our tfs:

- Feature1
- Trunk
- Release

Release branch have few months now and we only want to merge finished/tested stuff there.
Not long ago, we merged lot of new functionallity from Feature1 to trunk, that should NOT go the Release branch. Sadly, it turned out, that **some** of the functionallity should go to Release branch after all.

**Simpliefied** example:
Merged from *Feature1 -> Trunk* following changesets
Changsets *1000*, *1001* and *1002*.
Commited this merge to trunk in a single check-in.

Now I would like to merge *1001* to Release. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know the only way to achieve this, is to do a rollback on the single changeset and merge them one by one.

Comment: I have removed it...The post does not go live till Monday. I will repost when it is available...